# Identification of Integer valued ARIMA process, INARIMA

Tags: r, arima

I was wondering if there is any tools like R that can be used to identify the Integer valued ARIMA process? I know that using forecast package in R we can identify the ARIMA process , is there any package for INARIMA?

Comment: Excuse the possibility of my ignorance, but I've never heard of INARIMA. Furthermore, my attempt to find documentation about INARIMA has resulted in failure. Could you please confirm that you're not confusing an "Integer" ARIMA process with an "Integrated" ARIMA process? Alternatively, tell us what is meant by "Integer" ARIMA. This might help us to answer your question.

Comment: It has been introuduced by researchers as a tool for modeling counting processes, please see the link for more information:http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1987.tb00438.x/abstract

Comment: I think I may have found you the R package that you've been looking for. It is a package called ZIM. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ZIM/ The [PhD dissertation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&ved=0CHoQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fir.uiowa.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D3166%26context%3Detd&ei=ZrLJUd_GNIPDhAeNhIGoAg&usg=AFQjCNELpUlQLZ_yN-QmntfGmG2YU2iRfg&sig2=_v27wPQk1mu1ld7KGIAfcw) of the package author seems to give an overview of the package. Hopefully this is what you've been looking for.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh I didn't see any concern for level shifts or even pulses or determinstic  time trends in the ZIM  documentation.. Do the authors just assume that these effects don;t exist with integer data ?

Comment: A more general solution (using glm from `tscount` package is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362695/how-to-forecast-integer-time-series-in-r)